# Google Chrome black window in Fedora under VMware Workstation

Tags: google-chrome, fedora, vmware-workstation

After installing and running Chrome in Fedora, OS shows a black window region for Chrome. I cannot resize or do anything in this black area.

I had already rebooted, increased virtual video memory, but nothing works.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Specification:

- Chrome latest
- VMware workstation 12
- Fedora 4.10.15-200.fc25.x86_64

Answer (score 2):

I had to disable video acceleration. Now Chrome is showing up:
[image]

Comment: Can you try this command with **enabling** 3D graphics. Command:: `chrome --disable-gpu-compositing --disable-dwm-composition --disable-gpu`. Does it work?

Comment: `$ /opt/google/chrome/chrome --disable-gpu-compositing --disable-dwm-composition --disable-gpu` shows an error: 
`[3027:3027:0520/143533.279264:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] Gtk: cannot open display:`

Just to inform a new strange behavior. After this configuration, I am not able to paste text from Windows Host into Fedora Linux Guest operating system. It Copy and Paste from host to guest was working before disabling 3D graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the direction @Biswa.
I just used the "--disable-gpu-compositing" flag and was able to get Chrome working in VMware Workstation 12 with 3D Acceleration enabled.

Output from chrome://gpu

- Graphics Feature Status
- Canvas: Hardware accelerated
- Flash: Hardware accelerated
- Flash Stage3D: Hardware accelerated
- Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Hardware accelerated
- Compositing: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
- Multiple Raster Threads: Disabled
- Native GpuMemoryBuffers: Software only. Hardware acceleration
  disabled
- Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
- Video Decode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- Video Encode: Hardware accelerated
- VPx Video Decode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
- WebGL: Hardware accelerated
- WebGL2: Hardware accelerated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (and same parameters as Kiwisapo, running VMWare under Windows 10); Per Biswa, I ran

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --disable-gpu-compositing --disable-dwm-composition --disable-gpu &
```

Chrome came right up. I shut the machine down, unchecked "Accelerate 3D Graphics", started the machine back up and it runs fine now. Ugh.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  Please take the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.